# Intel MKL function error (C++)

Tags: c++, intel-mkl

I was trying to test the speed MKL of Intel but it gives a warning and an error as,

```
ipo : warning #11021: unresolved @cblas_sdot@20
1>          Referenced in ipo_36165obj.obj
1>ipo : error #11023: Not all components required for linking are present on command line
```

The cpp file:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <mkl_cblas.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

int main () {

float a[3], b[3], c;

a[0] = 1.f;
a[1] = 2.f;
a[2] = 3.f;

b[0] = 4.f;
b[1] = 5.f;
b[2] = 6.f;

int num = 1e5;
bool key = 0;

clock_t sTime = clock();

if (key) {

    for (int i=0; i<num; ++i) {

        c = cblas_sdot(3,a,1,b,1);
    }
}
else {

    for (int i=0; i<num; ++i) {

        c = a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2];
    }
}

clock_t elap = clock() - sTime;
float eTime = elap / ((float) CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

if (eTime > 60) {eTime /= 60; std::cout << ">> elapsed time : " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << eTime << " min" << std::endl;}
else {std::cout << ">> elapsed time : " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << eTime << " sec" << std::endl;} 

std::cin.ignore();  

return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

The command line for linker:

`/OUT:"C:\Users\Orxan\videos\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\arrTut\Release\arrTut.exe" /NOLOGO "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Release\arrTut.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\Orxan\videos\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\arrTut\Release\arrTut.pdb" /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /PGD:"C:\Users\Orxan\videos\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\arrTut\Release\arrTut.pgd" /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86`

The compiler command line:

`/Zi /nologo /W3 /O2 /Ob2 /Oi /Ot /Oy /Qipo /GA /Qparallel /D "_MBCS" /EHsc /GS /Gy /fp:fast /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Release\arrTut.pch" /Fa"Release\" /Fo"Release\" /Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /Gr`

Comment: Well.... this is a linker error; how did you invoke the linker?

Comment: I.e., show the command you used to compile/link the program, `$ g++ ...` or whatever.

Comment: I only see standard MSVC and Windows libs in your link line.  Add the intel library (whatever it may be named) to the correct place in the project's link options.  Sometimes in MSVC land a #pragma is used to link. See `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153901`